# How to create folder inside the folder in Drive through Google script?

Tags: jquery, html, forms, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I have used a existing folder ID to upload files, But I like to create folder by user's name whenever user pressed the submit button.
Please have a look at my [form](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbysotI7av0IdTvmGcb-1BEqQB7tT93t1J33d4Ync0M/dev). Help me to solve this issue.

JS:

```js
var dropBoxId = "123454567567"; // Drive ID of 'dropbox' folder
var logSheetId = "xoxoxoxooxoxox"; // Drive ID of log spreadsheet

function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('InputForm.html');
}

function uploadFiles(formObject) {
  try {
    // Create a file in Drive from the one provided in the form
    var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(dropBoxId);
    var person = createFolder(ajith);
    var blob1 = formObject.myFile1;  
    var blob2 = formObject.myFile2;  
    var blob3 = formObject.myFile3;  
    var file1 = person.createFile(blob1);    
    var file2 = person.createFile(blob2);    
    var file3 = person.createFile(blob3);    
    file.setDescription("Uploaded by " + formObject.myName);

    // Open the log and record the new file name, URL and name from form
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(logSheetId);
    var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
    sheet.appendRow([formObject.myName, formObject.myEmail, formObject.myCert, formObject.myExp, formObject.mySkills, formObject.myFees, formObject.myLoc, formObject.myTravel, file1.getName(),file2.getName(),file3.getName(), file1.getUrl(),file2.getUrl(),file3.getUrl(), file.getDateCreated() ]);

    // Return the new file Drive URL so it can be put in the web app output
    return file.getUrl();
  } catch (error) {
    return error.toString();
  }
}
```

```html
HTML:
<form>
<h2 class="text-center title">Application Form</h2>
<div class="col-sm-6" id="myForm">
  <div><label>Name:</label><input type="text" name="myName" placeholder="Your full name..." required/></div>
  <div><label>Mobile Number:</label><input type="number" name="myNum" placeholder="Mobile number..." required/></div>
  <div><label>Email:</label><input type="email" name="myEmail" placeholder="Email ID..." required/></div>
  <div><label>Certificate:</label><input type="text" name="myCert" placeholder="Certificate Name..." required/></div>
  <div><label>Experience:</label><input type="number" name="myExp" placeholder="Experience in years..." required/></div>
  <div><label>Skills:</label><input type="text" name="mySkills" placeholder="Skills(seperate by comma).." required/></div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6" id="myForm">
  <div><label>Fees:</label><input type="text" name="myFees" placeholder="Fees..." required/></div>
  <div><label>Locality:</label><input type="text" name="myLoc" placeholder="Locality..." required/></div>
  <div><label>Willingness to travel:</label><select><option>Yes</option><option>No</option></select></div>
  <div><label>Attach your latest Photo 1</label><input name="myFile1" type="file" required/></div>
  <div><label>Attach your latest Photo 2</label><input name="myFile2" type="file" required/></div>
  <div><label>Attach your latest Photo 3</label><input name="myFile3" type="file" required/></div>
</div>
<input type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="Submit"
      onclick="google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(updateUrl)
          .withFailureHandler(onFailure)
          .uploadFiles(this.parentNode)" />
</form>

<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this

```
 var name ="Myfoldernanme";
 var newfolder = folder.createFolder(name);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. This code for creating folder inside the drive.But I want to create a folder inside the existing folder, That folder ID has been given (dropBoxId ).